# binding needs time in selectbox

Tags: jquery

There are 2 selectbox when selecting the 1st select box option the corresponding option will show in the 2nd selectbox which is taking from db.when giving this `$('.optInSrcAccount').val(arr[10]);` it selects the option of the 1st selectbox. The 2nd selectbox showing the option after taking form db corresponding to the 1st selectbox option, and when giving this `$('#optExBankAccount').val(arr[11]);` it is not changing.the 1st oselectbox option is selected but not the 2nd.pls help me

```
            $('.pInfoExp').live('dblclick',function(){
              var arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
              if(arr[1]=='edit'){

                    $('.optInSrcAccount').val(arr[10]);
                    $('.optInSrcAccount').change();


                    if(arr[10] == 1 && arr[10]){ 

                    $('#optExBankAccount').val(arr[11]);
                    $('#optExBankAccount').change();

                    }
                    $("#popExpence" ).dialog({
                          resizable: true,
                          height: 500,
                          width: 1200,
                          modal: true,
                          buttons: {
                          },
                          close: function() {

                          }
                    });
              }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem some more, at the moment it makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.optInSrcAccount').change(function(){
    //do some thing
  });
```

In order to above method programetically you need to write this

```
     $('.optInSrcAccount').trigger('change');



  $('#ddlFirst').change(function(){
    //do some thing
    Bind2ndDropdown();

  });
```